# Cannot sign-in after expanding ubuntu(VM) hdd size

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I was working normally inside my Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. While installing some new packages I realized I only had a remaining 15% of the hdd volume available and as some of the packages I wanted to install are big I just decided to expand the virtual disk space from 40GB to 50GB.

In order to do that I shutdown the VM and expanded the size to 50GB using the VMware Workstation 12 GUI. After doing so I was planning to expand the volume inside the VM using gparted but now I cannot even sign-in in my user nor the guest. I can see my user in the select user and sign-in screen but when I input my password it seems to be trying to log-in and then fades to a black screen and returns to the select user screen.

I got the "cannot connect to the sata1:0 device" error message a couple of times while rebooting the VM but it's not even showing anymore. I will like to savage the installation but if it's not possible accessing the information would be nice, some updated files didn't make it to the last backup.

PS: The host OS is Windows 10 x64 Pro.

Comment: I was able to connect to the sata device after some tries but the sign-in problem is still there even after reinstalling both lightdm and the whole xserver.

Comment: After being able to access the sata device I was able to access my user and data. I solved the loop login problem login in my account and typing this command:
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak